# Website load speed around the world

Tags: web-server, website, performance

I would like to test a small website's loading speed around the world.

What are some relevant websites/tools that you find useful for this test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get your browser to following location and you will be impressed. At least i am ;)

http://www.webpagetest.org/

Answer (score 1):

It's not a web-site but a ping test tool. But can be interesting for you: http://just-ping.com/

It pings the server from a couple dozens of sources and displays the rtt.